# Python: value in dictionary won't set/update

Tags: python

This is the function I use, the strange thing is that the values do not get overwritten when the code uses data from "pct_data" (read from a tsv/csv file)

```
def get_percentages(objectcode, rp, af):
    cc_pct = {'PCT_MAT': 0
        , 'PCT_IUB': 0
        ,'PCT_UTV': 0
        ,'PCT_OWB': 0
        }
    if pct_data:
        print >> sys.stderr, lineno()
        # check OBJECTCODE
        for row in pct_data[:]:
            if( row['OBJECTCODE'] == objectcode ):
                print >> sys.stderr, lineno(), row
                cc_pct['PCT_MAT'] = row['PCT_MAT']
                cc_pct['PCT_IUB'] = row['PCT_IUB']
                cc_pct['PCT_UTV'] = row['PCT_UTV']
                cc_pct['PCT_OWB'] = row['PCT_OWB']
                print >> sys.stderr, lineno(), "%s %s %s %s" % (parse_float( row['PCT_MAT'].replace('-','0') ), parse_float( row['PCT_IUB'].replace('-','0') ), parse_float( row['PCT_UTV'].replace('-','0') ), parse_float( row['PCT_OWB'].replace('-','0') ) )
            else:
                for compensation, percentage in rp.items():
                    percentage = parse_float(percentage)
                    if ( 'ontw+beg/uitv' in compensation ):
                        cc_pct['PCT_UTV'] = percentage
                        cc_pct['PCT_OWB'] = percentage
                    if ( 'alle kosten' in compensation ):
                        cc_pct['PCT_MAT'] = percentage
                        cc_pct['PCT_IUB'] = percentage
                        cc_pct['PCT_UTV'] = percentage
                        cc_pct['PCT_OWB'] = percentage
                    if ( 'afbouw' in compensation or 'om niet' in compensation ):
                        cc_pct['PCT_MAT'] = (percentage * af) / 100
                        cc_pct['PCT_IUB'] = (percentage * af) / 100
                        cc_pct['PCT_UTV'] = (percentage * af) / 100
                        cc_pct['PCT_OWB'] = (percentage * af) / 100
    else:
        print >> sys.stderr, lineno()
        for compensation, percentage in rp.items():
            percentage = parse_float(percentage)
            if ( 'ontw+beg/uitv' in compensation ):
                cc_pct['PCT_UTV'] = percentage
                cc_pct['PCT_OWB'] = percentage
            if ( 'alle kosten' in compensation ):
                cc_pct['PCT_MAT'] = percentage
                cc_pct['PCT_IUB'] = percentage
                cc_pct['PCT_UTV'] = percentage
                cc_pct['PCT_OWB'] = percentage
            if ( 'afbouw' in compensation or 'om niet' in compensation ):
                cc_pct['PCT_MAT'] = (percentage * af) / 100
                cc_pct['PCT_IUB'] = (percentage * af) / 100
                cc_pct['PCT_UTV'] = (percentage * af) / 100
                cc_pct['PCT_OWB'] = (percentage * af) / 100
    if( objectcode == "HSTEN.0005" ):
        print >> sys.stderr, lineno(), cc_pct
    return cc_pct
```

print result

```
549
553 {'OBJECTCODE': 'HSTEN.0005', 'PCT_MAT': '46.00', 'PCT_OWB': '45.99', 'PCT_UTV': '45.99', 'PCT_IUB': '46.00'}
558
559 46.0 46.0 45.99 45.99
594 {'PCT_UTV': 0.0, 'PCT_MAT': 0.0, 'PCT_OWB': 0.0, 'PCT_IUB': 0.0}
```

Why won't the key values of "cc_pct" change to the values shown on row "553". I've tried several methods, but none of them work.

Comment: After going into the `if( row['OBJECTCODE'] == objectcode ):` block and changing `cc_pct`, in the next iteration of the loop it probably goes into the `else:` block and sets all the values in `cc_pct` to `percentage`, which seems to be 0.

Comment: write some tests

Comment: @Rawing I'm afraid you've nailed it for me. I just need to verify if that is the case. Thanks for getting my eyes focused

Comment: @Rawing I merely needed to add a "break" in the if( row['OBJECTCODE'] == objectcode ): statement. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved in comments:
 After going into the `if( row['OBJECTCODE'] == objectcode ):` block and changing `cc_pct`, in the next iteration of the loop it probably goes into the `else:` block and sets all the values in `cc_pct` to `percentage`, which seems to be `0`. – Rawing

I merely needed to add a `break` in the `if( row['OBJECTCODE'] == objectcode ):` statement. C. Gellings

Using this as `pct_dat`:

```
pct_data = [{'OBJECTCODE': 'HSTEN.0005', 'PCT_MAT': '46.00', 'PCT_OWB': '45.99', 'PCT_UTV': '45.99', 'PCT_IUB': '46.00'},]
```

Calling `print(get_percentages('HSTEN.0005',None,None))`
**Output:**

```
{'PCT_MAT': '46.00', 'PCT_UTV': '45.99', 'PCT_OWB': '45.99', 'PCT_IUB': '46.00'}
```

As I don't know about `rp, af` can't test the `else:` part!

Beside this it makes no sense why you have the `else:` part **twice**?

Comment: pct_data is not always available, but when it is, the data for a.o. PCT_MAT stays 0.0, whilst in all other cases it gets set